# How to speed up the loading time of my web page while parsing JSON file from URL

Tags: php, html, json

I'm getting data from a json file, accessed from URL,and the loading time is really long. However this website(https://gw2efficiency.com/) is actually getting same data, but some way manages to show them only when they are ready, and i would like to do it too.

I haven't found any clear way of doing this, i saw it might be an AJAX call but never used that.

this is where i show the data

```
<header>
<?php require 'getbag.php'?>
</header>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>Argent flat actuel: </span><br>
      <?php echo "  ".$gold ?><img alt="gold" src="gw2/images/gold_coin.png"><?php echo "  ".$silver ?><img  alt="silver" src="gw2/images/silver_coin.png"><?php echo "  ".$copper ?><img alt="copper" src="gw2/images/copper_coin.png">
    </div>
  </body>
```

And this is the file i call to get the data from the json file

```
getbag.php

<?php
$apikey = '<apikey>';
$headers = array(
'Accept-Language: fr',
'Authorization: Bearer '.$apikey.'',
);
$url='https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account/wallet';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$array1 = json_decode($result, true);
$value[] = $array1[0]['value'];
$id[] = $array1[0]['id'];
$total=$value[0];
$copper = substr($total, -2, 2);
$silver = substr($total, -4, 2);
$gold   = substr($total, 0, -4);


 ?>
```

I would like to see the html page instantly, if you have any idea how :).

Comment: Clear your api key for security !

Comment: What has been said above! You need to delete the old and generate a new API key NOW. The key can be used by anyone, anywhere to access the guildwars api to view your account info and it has a broad range of permissions. Do that here: https://account.arena.net/applications

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a simple way to make a request to to a server asynchronously from the frontend(javascript). So in your example you wish to hit the guildwars endpoint. As you can see in the code below, I make an ajax request to your endpoint, set the same headers and define a callback for when the response is successful. **console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));** will log the response to your browsers console. Then it's just a matter of accessing the javascript object.

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // view the this.responseText in your browser console log
      console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account/wallet", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "fr");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <apikeyGoesHere>");
  xhttp.send();
} 
loadDoc();
</script>
```